Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget
class ProfileView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => ProfileCubit(
        context.read<AuthenticationRepository>(),
        context.read<RemoteRepository>(),
        sessionCubit: context.read<SessionCubit>(),
      ),
      child: const ProfileViewContent(),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileViewContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileViewContent({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileViewContent> createState() => _ProfileViewContentState();
}

class _ProfileViewContentState extends State<ProfileViewContent>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<SessionCubit, SessionState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return state.authStatus.maybeWhen(
            <...>
            authenticated: (_) => DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: const _AuthenticatedAppBar(),
                body: CustomScrollView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  slivers: [               
                    <...>
                    const SliverFillRemaining(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          _MySightingsList(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  <...>
}

class _MySightingsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MySightingsList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ProfileCubit, ProfileState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
            <...>
            return GridView.builder(
              <...>
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                final item = state.records![i];

                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _onTapped(context, item);
                  },
                  <...>
  }

  void _onTapped(BuildContext context, Sighting item) {
    final Sighting sighting = item;
    final Atlas atlas = context.read<ProfileCubit>().state.activeAtlas;
    showModalBottomSheet(
      <...>
      builder: (context) => ContextMenu(
        items: [
          ContextMenuItem(
            <...>
          ),
          ContextMenuItem(
            <...>
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                  ),
                  <...>
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          translate("activities.delete_popup.description"),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 24),
                        CustomElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await context
                                .read<ProfileCubit>()
                                .deleteSighting(sighting, atlas); // Throws error
                           <...>
  }

I have an issue in my flutter app. When the deleteSighting() function is being called, I get the following error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ProfileCubit> above this Builder Widget

This doesn't seem to happen at other points in my _onTapped function, for example I can access my "state.activeAtlas" just fine. I don't really understand why that is the case. Can someone help me out here?

showModalBottomSheet creates a new route with its own BuildContext.
To access the Bloc or Provider within the modal bottom sheet, you should either use a callback or pass the Bloc into showModalBottomSheet
Sample
...
final profileCubit = context.read<ProfileCubit>();
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheetContent(
      onDeleteButtonPressed: () {
        profileCubit.add(NewEvent());
      },
    );
  },
);

or
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context),
      child: BottomSheetContent(),
     );
  },
);

